# Proper way to store no date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I'm moving a website to a new server and am having issues saving a date field with no date. The old server works fine but the new one must not be allowing a MySql empty value to be stored. My php code and database are identical on both servers so I'm assuming this is a MySql configuration difference. The old server is 5.7.36 and the new one is 5.7.38 I can't find any documentation that there was a change in storing dates between these versions so I assume this is a MySql configuration difference. I do not have access to the MySql configuration because these are shared servers. I can request a change be made but I am hoping there is a proper way to do this in my code.

My page has several date input fields on it. Some will have dates some will not. Those that don't will have the html input default which looks like a placeholder mm/dd/yyyy. When I post from the page the value for these mm/dd/yyyy fields are empty. MySql will not accept an empty date or 0000-00-00. I'm assuming the old server has the configuration altered to allow an empty or 0000-00-00 date and that's why it is working.

What is the proper way to pass this empty date value to MySql? I've tried
`$licenseExpires2=null;`  and `$licenseExpires2===NULL;` but neither worked. The datatype in MySql is DATE, default is NULL, which I need to remain for sorting issues.

Here is my input: `input name="licenseExpires2" type="date" id="licenseExpires2" value="">`

Here is the post data: `$licenseExpires2=$_POST['licenseExpires2'];`

Any valid date works fine. But click the "x" on the input box to remove the date and nothing will save or update.

Comment: Please show the insert code, the table definition, and the error message you are receiving.

Comment: likely a difference in sql_mode; check `select @@sql_mode` on both servers, specifically STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or NO_ZERO_IN_DATE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461744/global-setting-in-mysql-to-interpret-empty-string-as-null-for-date-field might be of some help here

Comment: The proper way to store an absent value is to use NULL. I recommend do not make the sql_mode allow invalid date values. If you can't find 0000-00-00 on a calendar, then it's not a date, and you shouldn't put it in a date column.

Comment: `$query="UPDATE employee SET licenseExpires2='$licenseExpires2' WHERE uniqueid='$uniqueid'";`

Comment: @@sql_mode shows "NO_ZERO_IN_DATE" & "NO_ZERO_DATE"

Comment: Why would this not work? $licenseExpires2=null; OR $licenseExpires2===NULL;

Comment: What is that? It's not SQL.

Comment: A php var to send to the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would code it using PDO:

```
$licenseExpires2=$_POST['licenseExpires2'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO mytable SET licenseExpires2 = ?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$licenseExpires2]);
```

I'm assuming PDO exceptions have been enabled, otherwise it's necessary to check the return value from both prepare() and execute().